# Format Date momentjs

Tags: reactjs, date, momentjs

I would like to convert a date with momentjs, the date is on this format:

```
2021-10-10T00:00:00+02:00
```

In react js I do:

```
moment('2021-10-10T00:00:00+02:00').format('dd/mm/yyyy');
```

And that return me `"invalid date"`

Have you got any idea about this error ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just have the format specified inside the moment constructor. Check the snippet below.

For different formatting options, check their docs https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/

```js
const date = "2021-10-10T00:00:00+02:00";
const formatted = moment(date, "YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss+ZZ").format("DD/MM/YYYY");
console.log(formatted);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.21.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this codesandbox which seems to be working with your input. Check if your import of moment has an issue.

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/react-playground-forked-f9zff?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Also note that if you want to format month it should be capital M - moment("2021-10-10T00:00:00+02:00").format("dd/MM/yyyy")

Answer (score 0):

You code is work for me. Please check your date input is same as you type.

```js
var time = moment('2021-10-10T00:00:00+02:00').format('DD/MM/YYYY');
$("body").text("The time is: "+time+".");
```

result:

```
The time is: 10/10/2021.
```

> If you know the format of an input string, you can use that to parse a moment.
>
> ```js
> moment("2021-10-10T00:00:00+02:00", "YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss+-HH:mm");
> ```
>
> If a time part is included, an offset from UTC can also be included as `+-HH:mm`, `+-HHmm`, `+-HH` or `Z`.
>
> ```
> 2013-02-08 09+07:00            # +-HH:mm
> 2013-02-08 09-0100             # +-HHmm
> 2013-02-08 09Z                 # Z
> 2013-02-08 09:30:26.123+07:00  # +-HH:mm
> 2013-02-08 09:30:26.123+07     # +-HH
> ```

[Moment Docs - Parse - String](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/)